# How to find duplicates using Kibana "Scripted Field"?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, calculated-field

I'm new to Elastic Stack. I have a question on how to count duplicated records.
My index is as follows. I want to check duplicates in `electric_id`

```
    {
  "_index": "testelectric-2020.07.22",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "2aef2aa9c3fb9fb41e32bc816d3d4c983a7be93e298a29914107153cdc",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "station": 1,
    "electric_id": "A2B7-000ACD21650F",
    "line": 5,
    "leak": 0.0044564689805,
    "dataname": "testelectric",
    "synced": false,
    "@timestamp": "2020-07-22T01:26:36.000Z",
    "lcr": 0.600109672546,
    "dmc": "#06MP    ###220720*1MUM0BL8K*=",
    "testtime": "2020-07-22T01:26:36.000Z",
    "judgement": true,
    "resistance": 0.486959082
  },
  "fields": {
    "testtime": [
      "2020-07-22T01:26:36.000Z"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2020-07-22T01:26:36.000Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1595381196000
  ]
}
```

So, here I hope to create a scripted field where I can detect how many times the electric_id is appeared.
Sample view would be like this( I have shorten it by ignoring the other fields)

```
| testtime                    | electric_id | number of duplicated counts(scripted field) |
| Jul 22, 2020 @ 03:26:36.000 | AAA         | 0                                           |
| Jul 22, 2020 @ 03:27:36.000 | AAA         | 1                                           |
| Jul 22, 2020 @ 03:28:36.000 | BBB         | 0                                           |
| Jul 22, 2020 @ 03:29:36.000 | CCC         | 0                                           |
| Jul 22, 2020 @ 03:30:36.000 | AAA         | 2                                           |
| Jul 22, 2020 @ 03:31:36.000 | BBB         | 1                                           |
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Why do you need a scripted field? You can simply run a `terms` aggregation on the `electric_id` field (with `min-doc_count: 2`) and you'll get your duplicates

Comment: @Val
Thanks for your comment. Actually, I want to omit all the duplicated records and I'm using timelion here. Any idea?